# Como acomodar la tabla dentro del PDF a exportar con jsPDF

Tags: ajax, spring, jspdf

Estoy intentando exportar una pagina a pdf con jsPDF, pero la tabla que se encuentra en su contenido me sale con la informacion desplazada. La aplicación esta creada en Spring Boot, utiliza Thymeleaf y el gestor de BD es PostgreSQL.

Este es parte del código de la página que quiero se exporte a pdf:

```
<div class="py-4 m-lg-5 flex-md-column">
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick="generatePDF()" style="top: 0; right: 0;">PDF</a>

    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header"><h2 class="text-secondary" th:text="${titulo}"></h2></div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div style="position: relative;" id="elementH">
                <img th:src="@{/img/aaa.png}" alt="Logo" class="responsive" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;" width="200px">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="content">
                <p><span th:text="${fecha_autorizo}"></span></p>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="content1">
                <p>A: <span th:text="${jefeCentro}"></span></p>
                <p>   <span th:text="${jefeCentro2}"></span></p>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="content2">
                <p>Compañero(a):</p>
                    <p>Texto</p>
                <p>Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior, le relaciono a continuación los servicios autorizados:</p>
            </div>
            <br>

            <div class="table-responsive" id="myTable">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Servicio</th>
                        <th>Nombre y Apellidos</th>
                        <th>Direccion</th>
                        <th>Sitio</th>
                        <th>Solicitado</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tbody class="table-group-divider">
                    <tr th:each="contratostelef: ${contratosTelefs}">
                        <td th:text="${contratostelef.servicio}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${contratostelef.nombre}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${contratostelef.direccion}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${contratostelef.sitio}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${contratostelef.solicitado}"></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="content3">
            <p>Sin otro asunto,</p>
            <br>
                <p><span th:text="${firma}"></span></p>
                <p><span th:text="${firma2}"></span></p>
                <p><span th:text="${firma3}"></span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

En JS utilice este código para exportar:

```
function generatePDF() {
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        var elementHTML = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
        var elementHTML1 = document.getElementById("content1").innerHTML;
        var elementHTML2 = document.getElementById("content2").innerHTML;
        var elementHTML3 = document.getElementById("content3").innerHTML;
        var tableHTML = document.getElementById("myTable").outerHTML;
        var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
                return true;
            }
        };
        doc.setFontSize(16);
        doc.fromHTML(elementHTML + elementHTML1 + elementHTML2 + tableHTML + elementHTML3, 15, 15, {
            'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
        doc.save('Oferta.pdf');
    }
```

El problema radica principalmente en la forma en que aparece la tabla dentro del pdf. La misma muestra los datos, pero la información aparece desplazada. ¿De qué forma puedo acomodar la tabla?

[image: contenido desplazado en las tablas]